# PHP if statement after a condition not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to use a nested If statement to test if a number is numeric, and if it is round the number and then move on to the next If statement to test if it's even. The problem I'm getting is that it isn't rounding the number, but instead just going on to the next if statement. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function CheckIfEven($NumberToCheck)
{
    if (is_numeric($NumberToCheck))
    {
        round($NumberToCheck , 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); 
        if ($NumberToCheck % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo "The number is even. <br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "The number is not even. <br />";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The value entered is not numeric. <br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: `round` does not modify the variable; it returns the rounded number.

Comment: it should be `$NumberToCheck  = round($NumberToCheck , 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);`

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it was something obvious. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `round` simply **returns** the rounded value, so you need to assign the number to itself:

```
<?php
$NumberToCheck = round($NumberToCheck, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
?>
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the return value of of round() in a variable and then use that for the rest of your operations:

```
$rounded = round($NumberToCheck , 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

if ($rounded % 2 == 0)
```